# A field in a php mail form doesn't register user input

Tags: php, jquery, html, phpmailer

I am trying to add another input field to my contact form on my website. The default form came with a name, email and message field. I am trying to also add the subject field.

The issue is that it doesn't record any input in the subject field. So when I receive the email, all the default fields have recorded the input correctly, but my addition of subject field is empty.

Below is the relevant html, javascript (for ajax) and php code:

```js
//Listens for Submit button, prevents page refresh and calls on submitForm()
$("#contactForm").submit(function(event) {
  // cancels the form submission
  event.preventDefault();
  submitForm();
});


//Grabs form input, and starts an ajax object
function submitForm() {
  // Initiate Variables With Form Content
  var name = $("#name").val();
  var email = $("#email").val();
  var messagesubject = $("#messagesubject").val();
  var message = $("#message").val();

  //I have added "&messagesubject=" + messagesubject to the data: to get input in the subject field
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "php/form-process.php",
    data: "name=" + name + "&email=" + email + "&messagesubject=" + messagesubject + "&message=" + message,
    success: function(text) {
      if (text == "success") {
        formSuccess();
      }
    }
  });
}

function formSuccess() {
  $("#msgSubmit").removeClass("hidden");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.11.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.1/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-12">
  <div class="contact-form">
    <h3>Send us a message. We're here to help!</h3>
    <form role="form" id="contactForm">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
          <label for="name" class="h4">Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter name" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
          <label for="email" class="h4">Email</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="messagesubject" class="h4 ">Subject</label>
        <input type="messagesubject" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Subject" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="message" class="h4 ">Message</label>
        <textarea id="message" class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Enter your message" required></textarea>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" id="form-submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg pull-right ">Submit</button>
      <div id="msgSubmit" class="h3 text-center hidden">Message Submitted!</div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is the PHP code to handle phpmail and get that message to my email. Couldn't include it in the snippet, but it's a pretty simple phpmail setup.

```
<?php
$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$MessageSubject = $_POST["MessageSubject"];
$message = $_POST["message"];

$EmailTo = "support@company";
$Subject = "$messagesubject from $name";

// prepare email body text
$Body .= "Name: ";
$Body .= $name;
$Body .= "\n";

$Body .= "Email: ";
$Body .= $email;
$Body .= "\n";

$Body .= "Subject: ";
$Body .= $messagesubject;
$Body .= "\n";

$Body .= "Message: ";
$Body .= $message;
$Body .= "\n";

// send email
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, .$MessageSubject "From:".$email);

// redirect to success page
if ($success){
   echo "success";
}else{
    echo "invalid";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`id="messagesubject"` is missing from the input field.

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="messagesubject" class="h4 ">Subject</label>
    <input type="messagesubject" class="form-control" id="messagesubject" placeholder="Enter Subject" required>
  </div>
```

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck with the rest.